# Is Jquery a javascript library?

Tags: jquery

I'm going to a competition, where we'll have to construct a web page,I'm planning to use Jquery in my web page. We are not allowed to use internet,is it even possible to use Jquery without linking?
**EDIT**:I'm not supposed to download or do anything new, I'm supposed to use the files and media ***they give!***

Comment: What do you mean with "not linkin"? jQuery is a JS library. You can download it and include it in your page, so you don't need an internet connection. http://jquery.com

Comment: Download it [from here](https://jquery.com/download/) and then you can use it offline (Download [this one](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js) if you don't care about IE < 9, or [this](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js) one if you do)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to bring the jquery source library file with you on USB flash drive and then link this file in your site.

Then you can reference it in your page in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="  **source of jQuery**  "></script>
```

Comment: so maybe they don't want to use jQuery and this is especially because of this